# Posso fazer um override em anottation já existentes no .net?

Tags: c#, .net, atributos

Tenho o seguinte annotation:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
```

Eu gostaria de ver o código que tem por trás dela, para eu criar a minha própria com base nela

Ou se tem como sobreeecrever ela

Comment: Só considere que a `Annotation` em si não deve possuir o código que vai setar de fato gerar o XML, ela apenas é utilizada por outro objeto, como o `XmlSerializer` que verifica se um atributo a ser serializado está decorado com essa `XmlElementAttribute` para executar uma determinada condição ou outra (nesse caso de serializar um atributo mesmo sendo null). Portanto você deveria procurar no `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 2):

O ReSharper pode decompilar o código do atributo (assim como de qualquer outra coisa), sendo que assim você poderia ver o código do mesmo.

Você também pode ver o [código do mesmo online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlElementAttribute.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Com um plugin chamado .NET Reflector você consegue acessar o código da annotation e ver como é trabalhado.

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)